# Codeigniter project social igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, installation, social-networking

Trying to install socialigniter on xampp server it's codeigniter social network project. But when i starting installation and opening localhost/socialigniter/install.php getting this error ?  i don't lnow what error is this just this text on page

```
{"status":"success","message":"Created files & folders","data":{"base_url":"","hostname":"","username":"","password":"","database":""}}
```

this is a install.php page source

```
    <?php

// Config File Constants
define('CONFIG_PATH', './application/config/config.php');
define('DATABASE_PATH', './application/config/database.php');
define('ROUTES_PATH', "./application/config/routes.php");
define('SOCIAL_IGNITER_PATH', './application/config/social_igniter.php');

// Proceed with DB Setup?
$proceedWithSetup = isset($_POST["hostname"]);

if ($proceedWithSetup) {

    // Database
    // We should probably clean these, as they could in theory come from anywhere on the web
    $hostname = $_POST["hostname"];
    $username   = $_POST["username"];
    $password   = $_POST["password"];
    $database_name = $_POST["database"];

    // Before we change any files, we should try connecting to the db using the given credentials
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $hostname . ';dbname=' . $database_name, $username, $password, array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
            PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 10));
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        // If it went wrong: complain
        header('HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error'); // TODO: Check if this works across most PHP platforms
        echo $e -> getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // If all's good: woo! Edit the config files
    $database_file = file_get_contents("./application/config/database.php", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    $database_file = str_replace("{INSTALL_DB_HOSTNAME}", $hostname, $database_file);
    $database_file = str_replace("{INSTALL_DB_USERNAME}", $username, $database_file);
    $database_file = str_replace("{INSTALL_DB_PASSWORD}", $password, $database_file);
    $database_file = str_replace("{INSTALL_DB_DATABASE}", $database_name, $database_file);
    file_put_contents(DATABASE_PATH, $database_file);

    // Config
    $config_file    = "./application/config/config.php";
    $encryption_key = sha1(microtime(true).mt_rand(10000,90000));
    $config_current = file_get_contents($config_file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    $config_current = str_replace("{INSTALL_BASE_URL}", $_POST["base_url"], $config_current);
    $config_current = str_replace("{INSTALL_ENCRYPTION_KEY}", $encryption_key, $config_current);
    file_put_contents(CONFIG_PATH, $config_current);

    // Make Files
    copy("./application/config/routes.php", ROUTES_PATH);
    copy("./application/config/social_igniter.php", SOCIAL_IGNITER_PATH);

    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'Created files & folders',
            'data' => $_POST
        )
    );

} else {
    // Write HTML for setup Forms etc
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Install Social-Igniter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/install.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/social.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/installer/setup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="content norm_top"></div>    
    <div class="content norm_mid">  
        <div id="welcome" class="content_wrap">
            <img id="logo" src="images/si_logo.png">
            <h1>Install Social-Igniter</h1>
            <p>Welcome and thanks for downloading Social-Igniter, you have taken the first step to setting up your own little corner on the web. Great job!</p>
            <p>Next, we need you to tell us a few things before your site will work properly.</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="norm_separator"></div>
        <div class="content_wrap">
        <?php
                // Check all the files we want to write are writable
                $all_writable = true;
                $errors = '<ul>';
                if (!is_writable(CONFIG_PATH))
                {
                    $all_writable = false;
                    $errors .= '<li><code>' . CONFIG_PATH . '</code></li>';
                }
                if (!is_writable(DATABASE_PATH))
                {
                    $all_writable = false;
                    $errors .= '<li><code>' . DATABASE_PATH . '</code></li>';
                }
                if (!is_writable(ROUTES_PATH))
                {
                    $all_writable = false;
                    $errors .= '<li><code>' . ROUTES_PATH . '</code></li>';
                }
                if (!is_writable(SOCIAL_IGNITER_PATH))
                {
                    $all_writable = false;
                    $errors .= '<li><code>' . SOCIAL_IGNITER_PATH . '</code></li>';
                }
                $errors .= '</ul>';

                if (!$all_writable)
                {
                    // Echo error messages
                    echo '<div class="warning"><strong>Oops! SocialIgniter can\'t install itself because it can\'t update some config files.</strong><p>To fix this, the following files must be made writable by PHP or your web server:</p>';

                    echo $errors;

                    echo '<p>The <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions">WordPress Codex has a good page on permissions</a>. If you need more help, ask your sysadmin or get in contact with the <a href="https://github.com/socialigniter/socialigniter/">SocialIgniter Developers</a></p><p>Once you\'ve fixed this, try refreshing this page.</p></div>';
                }
                else
                {               
            ?>
            <!-- step 1 -->
            <div id="step_1" class="hide">
            <form name="install_step_1" id="install_step_1" method="POST">
                <h2>Site URL</h2>
                <p><label>Of your website: <input type="text" name="base_url" id="base_url" placeholder="http://example.com/"></label></p>

                <h2>Database Settings</h2>

                <p>If you're on shared hosting, your provider should have sent you MySQL database credentials -- if not, contact them and ask for hostname, username, password and database name required to connect.</p>

                <div id="warning-container"></div>

                <ol>
                    <li><label>The hostname of your database server: <input type="text" id="db_hostname" placeholder="localhost" name="hostname"></label></li>
                    <li><label>The username used to connect to the database: <input type="text" id="db_username" placeholder="root" name="username"></label></li>
                    <li><label>The password used to connect to the database: <input type="password" id="db_password" placeholder="" name="password"></label></li>
                    <li><label>The name of the database you want to connect to: <input type="text" id="db_database" placeholder="social-igniter" name="database"></label></li>
                    <li><button type="submit" id="install_step_1_submit">Create Database tables and Continue</button></li>
                </ol>
            </form>
            </div>
            <!-- step 2 -->
            <div id="step_2" class="hide">
                <h2 id="step_2_title">Creating Database...</h2>     
            </div>
            <!-- step 3 -->
            <div id="step_3" class="hide">
            <form name="install_step_3" id="install_step_3" method="POST">
                <h2>Your Information</h2>
                <p>Enter information for who will be owning or controlling this website</p>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td>Name</td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="signup_name" placeholder="Joe Smith" value="">
                        <span id="signup_name_error"></span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Email</td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="signup_email" placeholder="your@email.com" value="">
                        <span id="signup_email_error"></span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                      <td>Password</td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="signup_password" placeholder="********" value="">
                        <span id="signup_password_error"></span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                      <td>Confirm Password</td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password_confirm" id="signup_password_confirm" placeholder="********" value="">
                        <span id="signup_password_confirm_error"></span> 
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Signup"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
                <input type="hidden" name="session" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="1">
            </form>
            </div>
            <!-- step 4 -->
            <div id="step_4" class="hide">
            <form name="install_step_4" id="install_step_4" method="POST">
                <h2>Website Information</h2>
                <p>So people know what website they are visiting :)</p>
                <p>Site Name<br> <input type="text" name="title" id="site_title" placeholder="My Awesome Website" value=""></p>
                <p>Tagline<br> <input type="text" name="tagline" id="site_tagline" placeholder="Where I Post All My Awesome Things" value=""></p>
                <p>Keywords<br> <input type="text" name="keywords" id="site_keywords" placeholder="awesome, things, pictures, videos, poems, watermelons, cats, ninjas" value=""></p> 
                <p>Description<br> <textarea name="description" id="site_description" placeholder="This is my awesome website where I post awesome stuff. Some of my favorite things are ninjas, watermelons, and cats" cols="40" rows="7"></textarea>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Continue"></p>
            </form>
            </div>  
            <!-- step 5 -->
            <div id="step_5" class="hide">
                <h2>Your Site is Now Setup</h2>
                <p>Good job old sport, you're awesome. Now go em get em tiger!</p>
                <h3>Get Started Exploring</h3>
                <p><a id="go_to_website" href=""><img src="application/views/dashboard_default/assets/icons/globe_24.png"> Site</a>
                <p><a id="go_to_dashboard" href=""><img src="application/views/dashboard_default/assets/icons/home_24.png"> Home</a>
                <p><a id="go_to_apps" href=""><img src="application/views/dashboard_default/assets/icons/installer_24.png"> Apps</a>
                <p><a id="go_to_design" href=""><img src="application/views/dashboard_default/assets/icons/colors_24.png"> Design</a>
            </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content norm_bot"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Dude that is clearly not an error. The clue is where it says `"status"="success"`. This, means fairly obviously, that stuff succeeded. Its a json string that you can grab and parse to decide to do other stuff with

Comment: @MikeMiller it is an error - its the first step in a multi step install process, not something to be parsed by the user.

Comment: Right yes I got you guys now. Strictly speaking the output described does not constitute an error but an unexpected result

Answer (score 0):

confirming that i just wrestled with this and got multiple errors including what you got. the other commenter is not correct, its supposed to go to the next step in the install.

there's a thread on github for this project with people trying to install, getting errors - and the original developer saying that he's full time on another project and can't maintain it.

there's obviously some great stuff in this project so if you debug the install please post again.

Comment: OK fair point and apologies for missing it. The expectation is that the code does something with this json and isn't currently doing it. Is this right?

Comment: multi step installer script is failing. startRant: i wonder how many open source projects got hosed just because of the installer? i know i've wasted so much time trying to debug different ones. just give us some sql files and we can set up the database tables in a few seconds! /endRant

Comment: `echo 'Rant approval process initiated'; echo 'Rant approval status = true';// (assuming json was parsed correctly)`. In defence of the author it's not his/her job to properly research solutions. If it isn't working don't f-in use it